# Some problems with doing math to subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Right so, I'm trying to get a percentage with two values that are retreived from a subquery. Problem is, every time I do that, I get same values for every column, 5000.

```
select *, 
       sum(100*(totalwon / (total / 100))) as percentage 
from
    (SELECT *, count(winnername) + count(losername) as total, count(winnername) as totalwon 
     FROM versus group by winnername) q1
group by 
   winnername
```

The table, versus looks like this:

```
ID |  WINNERNAME   | LOSERNAME
```

If I do totalwon + total, it correctly sums everything into a separate column - why is that?

Oh and sorry for not formatting the message correctly, there isn't instructions anywhere near to do that.

Here's it in a bit more extensive way:

```
ID | WINNERNAME |LOSERNAME | TOTAL | TOTALWON |PERCENTAGE
1    player 1   | Player 2 | 16    |   8      | 5000
2  | player 3   | player 4 | 8     |   6      | 5000
3  | player 4   | player 6 | 4     |   4      | 5000
```

That's what the above query gives me.
But if I change it from the percentage calculation to just sum between those two columns, it works as it should:

```
ID | WINNERNAME |LOSERNAME | TOTAL | TOTALWON | Sum
1    player 1   | Player 2 | 16    |   8      | 24    #Obviously there's 16 total occurences with player 1 as the winner, therefore total = 16
2  | player 3   | player 4 | 8     |   6      | 14
3  | player 4   | player 6 | 4     |   4      | 8
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: Sorry. The above query gives me:
`code`
ID | WINNERNAME |LOSERNAME | PERCENTAGE
1    player 1   | Player 2 | 5000
2  | player 3   | player 4 | 5000
3  | player 4   | player 6 | 5000

But if I change it from the percentage calculation to just sum between those two tables, it works as it should

Comment: Your query doesn't fully make sense.  Please edit your question and add sample data from `versus`.

Comment: Do you have another table of all unique possible players too?

Answer (score 0):

calc the sums that way:

```
 select *, 
   (100 * sum(totalwon) / sum(total)) as percentage 
 from
    (SELECT *, count(winnername) + count(losername) as total, count(winnername) as totalwon 
      FROM versus group by winnername) q1
 group by winnername
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I think you are encountering is the count(winner or loser).  A count of logical will always return 1 if true (or has a value).  So I dont see how your counts are actually working as you are not doing distinct of the losers.  So, if a person has 10 matches, I would expect the counts to show 10 win, 10 loss as each column just has a name.

Now, that being said, I would think you have yet another table that has a list of all possible players that could be a match.  From that, I would do a two separate subqueries per respectiv ename and position (win/lose) and left-join them to get answer.  Something like

```
select
      P.PlayerName,
      coalesce( winners.timesWin, 0 ) as Wins,
      coalesce( losers.timesLost, 0 ) as Losses,
      case when coalesce( winners.timesWin, 0 ) 
              + coalesce( losers.timesLost, 0 ) = 0 then 0
           else coalesce( winners.timesWin, 0 ) 
              / (   coalesce( winners.timesWin, 0 ) 
                  + coalesce( losers.timesLost, 0 ) ) * 100 end as PctWins
   from
      Players p
         LEFT JOIN ( select winnerName as player,
                            count(*) as timesWin
                        from versus
                        group by winnerName ) winners
            on p.PlayerName = winners.player
         LEFT JOIN ( select loserName as player,
                            count(*) as timesLost
                        from versus
                        group by loserName ) losers
            on p.PlayerName = losers.player
```

This way, you are getting all possible players.  From that, you may have (and even in sample data shown), some players never win and some never lost.